# How to find supported Node.js version for Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I'm new to Node.js, and I'm wondering how to determine which version of Node.js a specific version of NestJS supports. I've checked the package-lock.json file for engines property, but it doesn't seem to provide this information. I also couldn't find any documentation on the NestJS website.

Specifically, I'd like to confirm if @nestjs/testing 9.4.0 is compatible with Node.js 18.

Answer (score 0):

Node 18 is compatible with Nest v9.

More specifically, Nest v9 is compatible with Node version 12 and up, except 13 for reasons of how the unstable build worked.

Nest v10 is only compatible with 16 and up, IIRC

Comment: When I updated the node version to 18, I got the segmentation fault error, I tried to update the nest.js packages too, that time also I got the same error

Comment: It might help if you provide what the error is

Comment: I got this error message while running my application ```Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the docs site

you can find that info here: https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#prerequisites